# How can I interpret the chi-square plot from Benford.Analysis R package

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

When you plot the results after applying the [benford.analysis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/benford.analysis/) R package, I get the following plot.
[image]

Here is the full set of plots that I get when using the package. I have not idea how to interpret the Cho-Squared Difference chart.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the chart is showing you is that there is a *substantive discrepancy* in the data where the first two digits are 50, when compared to what one should expect by Benford's Law --- these entries should be further investigated.